# Accidentally removed SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I accidentally removed the SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER reference in the "Swift Compiler - Code Generation" in the "Build Settings".

SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER is also known as "Install Objective-C Compatibility Header".

Is it possible to add it back in? It seems I can only add "User-Defined"-settings.

Comment: How did you remove it?

Comment: By removing the reference in the Build Settings of my target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to open the Xcode project file in a text editor (Sublime) and compared it with a new project. Copied the reference twice, for debug and release and that worked!

Answer (score -1):

For swift, you might also need include the module name in the include path. e.g. (#include "xxx/xxx.h", assuming xxx is the pod's name).